# Cloning the current SSD notebook windows to a larger one without buying extra hardware

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone

This question maybe repeated but I didn't find the answer I looking for in the other threads.

I have 2 HDD in my notebook:

1. SSD 128GB and consist of the windows partition
2. HDD 1 TB

I want to replace the SSD with a larger one (256 GB) without the need to buy extra hardware to clone the windows. Only cloning the current windows to the 1 TB hard disk then unzip it on the new SSD.

Is it possible to achieve and how?

Comment: It is not possible to just copy and paste your Windows installation to another drive.  You can clone your drive any number of third-party software solutions, but software reconsideration are specifically, out of scope here at Super User.  Most software require an drive to generate the image of the storage device, in order for you to then restore the image, onto a different disk.  Some software support the ability to clone a drive provided both drives are connected to the system at the same time.

Comment: Thank you.
Are there restrictions on the cloning process? e.g. 118 GB > 1 TB > 256 GB. someone said first I have to create virtual partition 118 GB on the 1 TB HDD. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual partition on the 1 TB HDD is not required to use Clonezilla.

1) Make a [Clonezilla LiveUSB](https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php).
2) Once made, shut down the PC.
3) Disconnect the HDD, and connect the larger SSD in its place.
4) Boot from the Clonezilla LiveUSB.
5) Use Clonezilla to [replicate the contents of the original SSD onto the larger SSD](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone). 
By default, Clonezilla clones the "same" size of source disk to target disk. If you want to make use all of the target disk size, remember to enter "Expert" mode and choose option "-k1".
6) Shut down, disconnect both SSDs, put the new SSD where the old SSD was, and put the HDD back where it was originally.
7) Start the PC and go into the BIOS.
8) Make sure the first boot device is Windows Boot Manager on the new SSD.

Comment: Thank you. The SSD is M.2 while the HDD is SATA, is it possible to connect the larger SSD to the SATA port without the need to some sort of hardware conversion?

Comment: That's a different issue. This is a Q&A site; one question at a time, reasonably scoped. See the Help guidelines linked below at left. In your follow on question, make sure to specify the make and model of laptop. Only the model part number from the serial number sticker please; other 'model' numbers elsewhere are marketing names and less useful.